# Brackets editor - How to display file tree/side bar to top horizontally?

Tags: adobe-brackets

Brackets side bar:[image]

I look around the brackets menu bar trying to display the sidebar similar to sublime, but no luck[image]:

I tried googling: "*brackets editor How to display file tree to top horizontal*" & "*brackets editor How to display sidebar to top horizontal*" but no good result.

Answer (score 2):

To get a classic tab bar in Brackets, you could try the (unfortunately named) [Tabs - Custom Working](https://github.com/DH3ALEJANDRO/custom-work-for-brackets) extension.

Demo gif from the extension GitHub page:
[image: Tabs - Custom Working in action]